# Add HTML to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JSON. My main objective is to create a jquery carousel that is populated using JSON. When I have something like this and I try to validate i get an error:

```
 {
    "error":"",
"hasMore":true,
"html":"<!-- Cache: Off -  --> <!-- MAIN COLUMN -->      <!-- PRODUCT RESULTS -->                    
<li class=\"product\"> ..."
}
```

the error is with the "html" when i run it in jsonlint.com i get this error:

```
Parse error on line 4:

...: true,"html": "<!-- Cache: Off -  
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: How you are encoding json??

Comment: The error was due to the line breaks

Comment: Why do you want to store HTML code in JSON, you should just store the content in your JSON file ie your IMG path and alt attribute.

Comment: dont ask me. i just need to turn it into a jquery carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **extra line breaks** before `li tag`,

```
{
    "error": "",
    "hasMore": true,
    "html": "<!-- Cache: Off --> <!-- MAIN COLUMN --> <!-- PRODUCT RESULTS --> <li class=\"product\"> ..."
}
```

`Validated` on **[Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)**

Answer (score 2):

You content (HTML) including the line break.

Update:

If you are using PHP, please `nl2br()` to escape "\n" before encode to json.

If you are using others language, please remove / escape "\n" before encode to json.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line break with `\n`, i.e. replace this:

```
"key": "before linebreak
after linebreak"
```

with this:

```
"key": "before linebreak\nafter linebreak"
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not allow new lines within strings.

```
{
    "error":"",
"hasMore":true,
"html":"<!-- Cache: Off -  --> <!-- MAIN COLUMN -->      <!-- PRODUCT RESULTS -->                    
<li class=\"product\"> ..."
}
```

Should be:

```
{
  "error":"",
  "hasMore":true,
  "html":"<!-- Cache: Off -  --> <!-- MAIN COLUMN -->      <!-- PRODUCT RESULTS -->                    \n<li class=\"product\"> ..."
}
```

The `\n` is what is important.